# Kill Control Pannel Applet (appwiz.cpl) from Vb.net Application

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am building a vb.net application which monitors external process and kills the process based on certain conditions. The application works great with monitoring .exe process but i m unable to use it with control pannel items.

Suppose a user launches programs and features , I want my vb.net app to detect it and kill it. Under task manager the process is shown as explorer.exe.

I can successfully launch programs and features using  `Process.Start(System.Environment.SystemDirectory + "\appwiz.cpl")`
but i cannot kill it this way, can anyone tell me how i could kill this process??

Thanks!

Comment: The program is only killed if a non-admin user is using the computer, its not a malware, its to prevent people from uninstalling important applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Process.Start("taskkill.exe /im explorer.exe")
```

Just replace `explorer.exe` with the process you wanna stop/kill...

Also works with the `PID` (Process ID):

```
Process.Start("taskkill.exe /pid /*yourPID*/")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not kill applications until there is other way to exit them.**
It is like finishing your day by instantly turning off your computer.

**First, at least ask applications to close themselves:** 
Please see Microsoft article [How to use Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005 to close another application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305602) how to implement closing request.

Also please have a look at this Q&A [how to prevent application to be uninstalled by a user (w/o admin rights)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4900857/2392157).